# how to save selected option into txt file in php?

Tags: php

I want to save selected option (color and favourite song) into result.txt file. Its already save it but saves empty values. Can somebody explain why its saving empty values? it says Undefined index: color in...., Undefined index: song in...   Here is my code

```
<?php
   echo "<meta charset='utf-8'>";

   echo "<form method='get' action='ques.php'>
what color do you like? <br>";   
$co = file('color.txt');
$col = ' ';
$col.="<option>choose</option>";
foreach ($co as $color) { 
    $choose = explode('-',$color);
    $col .= '<option value="'.$choose[0].'">'.$choose[0].'</option>';
}
$select = '<select name="color">'.$col.'</select>';
echo $select;


  echo "<br><br>What is yor favourite song? <br>";            
$song = file('song.txt');
$sing = '-';
$sing.="<option>choose</option>";
foreach ($song as $son) {
    $choosen = explode('-',$son);
    $sing .= '<option value="'.$choosen[0].'">'.$choosen[0].'</option>';
}
$select = '<select name="song">'.$sing.'</select></form>';
echo $select; 


  echo "<form method='get' action='ques.php'>
<br><input type='submit' name='save' value='Save it'>
 </form>";      



   if (!empty($_GET['save'])){

      $fl="result.txt";
      $flo=fopen($fl,"a");
      $content=$_GET["color"]."*".$_GET["song"]."*=\r\n";
      fputs($flo,$content);
      fclose($flo);   
}
?>
```

Comment: Form elements (like select-boxes) must be _inside_ the form. You're outputting the select-boxes _before_ the form, which means that they don't belong to the form at all. The only thing your form contains is a submit-button so that's the only thing that will be submitted.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ If you just want to add a line to a text file, you can do it with one single line: `file_put_contents('result.txt', 'The content', FILE_APPEND);`. No need to use `fopen(), fputs() and fclose();`.

Comment: I form it but it still saving empty values :( It says Undefined index: color and song

Comment: Do some debugging. Add `var_dump($_GET):` as the first line after `if (!empty($_GET['save'])) {` and see what your form actually submits. You should also be able to see all the data in the URL when you've submitted the form since you're using `method="get"`

Comment: Could you please also add how you fixed the form-issue? If you keep getting `undefined index`, you can't have put the selectboxes properly inside the form.

Comment: its now edited. and now it saving values 'choose' not that values which i put into drop down list from txt file